# How to write only one file (append) in S3 using Kafka

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have kafka deployed on EKS. I'm using strimzi with schema registry. My Sink Connector is (abstracted):

```yaml
s3.part.size: 5242880
flush.size: 20000
rotate.schedule.interval.ms: 10000
transforms: "InsertField"
transforms.InsertField.type: "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value"
transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field: "integration_timestamp"
```

On my source connector I have:

```yaml
max.batch.size: 100000
max.queue.size: 100000
query.fetch.size: 10000
poll.interval.ms: 10000
```

I'm using parquet format and my data is partitioned. I'm writing (sink) to S3. I would like to know how to append data to one file only. My sink is set to append until the file reaches ~5MB, then generate a new one. Although, on S3 I'm getting a new file on every insert.

I noticed that on my connect logs I get:

```
Committing files after waiting for rotateIntervalMs time but less than flush.size records available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending data to a single file in Kafka Connect S3 Sink Connector while using formats like Parquet can be challenging because Parquet is a columnar storage format designed for efficient storage and retrieval. It is not optimized for appending data to an existing file. However, there are a few things you can do to minimize the number of files generated and get closer to your desired behavior.

1. Increase flush.size: You can increase the flush.size configuration property to a larger value, so that the connector accumulates more records before flushing them to a file. Keep in mind that increasing this value will also increase the memory usage of the connector, as it needs to buffer more records in memory.

   ```
    flush.size: 50000
   ```
2. Increase rotate.schedule.interval.ms: This configuration controls how often the connector checks whether it's time to rotate the output file. You can set a longer interval, so that the connector has more time to accumulate records before deciding to rotate the file. Note that this might cause the connector to create fewer, larger files, which could make it harder to manage or process the data in some cases.

   ```
    rotate.schedule.interval.ms: 3600000
   ```
3. Decrease s3.part.size: You can try decreasing the s3.part.size to a smaller value, so that a single file will fill up more quickly and the connector will start appending to the next file. However, this might lead to more frequent S3 API calls and increased costs.

   ```
    s3.part.size: 1048576
   ```
4. Decrease poll.interval.ms: You can decrease the poll.interval.ms configuration in your source connector to increase the frequency of polling for new records. This will result in more records being fetched and forwarded to the sink connector, increasing the chance of filling the buffer before the next file rotation.

   ```
    poll.interval.ms: 5000
   ```

Please note that even with these adjustments, it might not be possible to achieve a strict "one file only" behavior due to the nature of the Parquet format and the Kafka Connect framework's design. These suggestions should help reduce the number of files generated, but you may still need to develop a post-processing step to merge smaller files into larger ones, depending on your use case. Or try changing the file format to CSV or Avro.